# Internet Explorer can't get data from input type text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have input elements of `type="text"` like this:

```
<input type="text" class="f_taskname" value=""/>
```

When the user writes something into it and push enter, the next script works:

```
var task_name=$('#filter_body').find('.f_taskname').val();
```

and call ajax with parameters:

```
url:url,
dataType: 'text',
type:'get',
data: { task_name: task_name},
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
```

It works in Firefox and Chrome, but isn't working in Internet Explorer.
I've made a log file and it is getting data from task_name variable in the PHP script:

```
$f1=fopen('log.txt', 'w');
$output=$task_name.PHP_EOL;
fwrite($f1, $output);
fclose($f1);
```

It works fine with English words, but with Russian words it doesn't work, and in the log file I see things like Chinese symbols.

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `$( '.f_taskname' ).val()`

Comment: We need to see the function that you call and how the value is read within that function.

Comment: var task_name=$('#filter_body').find('.f_taskname').val();
$.ajax({
      url: 'getData.php?g_b_n',
      data: { task_name : taask_name },
      dataType: 'text',
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
     success: function(data){
             change_contnent(); 
  }
});

And i can get value, for example it successfully works with : task_name: '11121'
but it wont work with task_name : "Задача 1" 
In log file i m getting : 玎

Comment: Ilya: please [edit] code into the question, not the comments. That way everyone reading the question sees it without having to struggle to read it in the comments, where it's barely legible. Editing the question also serves to bump the question back to the front page (although I'm not sure how large a given edit has to be to do that). Incidentally, from what I can see you're reposting the same Ajax call we can already see in the question, which is not what @epascarello was asking for.

Comment: Are you setting the correct content/encoding headers on the php side?

Comment: Oh, i ve got it!

i change my function to
$.ajax({
data: { task_name : task_name },
type: 'post', .......
});

it seems like IE wont work with arguments in URL

Comment: yes, i did it
Ive set header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: @David Thomas ok, next time, ill do it! Thank you for the replyies!!!

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
 var taskname = $('.f_taskname').val();
```